# sed command to replace if( with if (

Tags: sed

I want to run a sed command : sed command to replace `if(` with `if (`

My command looks like this:

```
sed 's/if(/if ( /g' file1.c >file1.c
```

where `file1.c` contains the string that needs to be replaced.

Problem is file contents gets cleared and no changes are reflected.

Comment: You cannot redirect to the same file: it gets truncated first and then evaluated. Instead, use `sed -i '...' file` to do in-place replacement, or just redirect to another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try two different approaches.

If you want to update existing file:

```
sed -i 's/if(/if ( /g' file1.c
```

If you want to store the modified file in another file:

```
sed 's/if(/if ( /g' file1.c > file2.c
```

Comment: Solutions do not make sense. Also, why posting another answer?

Comment: I proposed you 2 differents way to edit you file content...
1st way is to edit existing. (overwrite)
2nd way crete a new file with the edit.

Comment: First one is not editing, will just show in the screen. Second has an unnecessary pipe, should just be `sed '...' file1.c > file2.c`

Comment: your're right !
sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
sed -re 's/if(/if ( /g'
```

Comment: No. Current command works, it is just a problem in the (re-)direction.